# Gradle java-library dependency issues

Tags: gradle

I have developed a Java library using the `java-library` Gradle plugin. This library has e dependency on `protobuf-java` which I need to expose as a transitive dependency to users of the library.

I have the following snippets in my library's build.gradle

```
plugins {
    id 'java-library'
    id "maven-publish"
    id "com.google.protobuf" version "0.8.16"
}

...

dependencies {
    api ("com.google.protobuf:protobuf-java:3.17.3")
    testImplementation("com.google.protobuf:protobuf-java-util:3.17.3")
    testImplementation("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.7.2")
    testImplementation("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:5.7.2")
}
```

Running `gradlew dependencies` gives me the following as expected

```
api - API dependencies for source set 'main'. (n)
\--- com.google.protobuf:protobuf-java:3.17.3 (n)
```

But when I add the library as a dependency to in my main app, I don't get any transitive dependencies. Doing a `gradlew dependencies` in my main app gives me:

```
compileClasspath - Compile classpath for source set 'main'.
+--- my-library:my-library:1.0.21
+--- javax.jms:javax.jms-api -> 2.0.1
....
```

What could be the cause for the dependency not showing up in the main app?

Answer (score 2):

The problem was with the maven-publish plugin.

I had to add the following to my `publishing` section to get it to work.

```
publications {
    mavenJava(MavenPublication) { from project.components.java }
}
```

Comment: hi I am having the same problem as yours, this is my question, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73436774/extended-class-method-are-not-available-when-exported-as-library can you help me on this ?