# Extended class method are not available when exported as library

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, gradle, nats.io

I am trying to build a java library (`streaming-client.jar`) and use it in client microservice.

Within this jar file I have one POJO class which is extending third party POJO classs

```
 @ConditionalOnClass({Options.class})
 @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "nats.spring")
 public class ServerProps extends NatsProperties {
 
   public ServerProps(){ super(); }
  }
```

Now this `NatsProperties` class is coming from third party library and this class extends another autoconfiguration class.

When I use `ServerProps` locally within this libary I can access the methods from `NatsProperties` super class.

But When I export this library as jar file. and use it in client application.

`NatsProperties` methods are not available via `ServerProps` class

At client

```
  ServerProps props = new ServerProps();
  props.server("sdfsfsdfsdf")//server method cant be resolved,
```

**EDIT**

I tried adding all the methods from `NatsProperties` class to my custom Class `StreamingServerProperties`

then when I tried to access them in other project like below

```
   StreamingServerProperties props = new StreamingServerProperties();
   props.server("serverUrl") //Intellij complains that Cannot access io.nats.spring.boot.autoconfigure.NatsProperties
```

**build.gradle of streaming-client.jar**

```
  plugins {
    id 'java-library'
    id 'maven-publish'
    id "com.github.johnrengelman.shadow" version "7.1.2"
  }

 group = 'com.dexter'
 version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
 sourceCompatibility = '11'

 repositories {
    mavenCentral()

  }

publishing {
     publications {
          mavenJava(MavenPublication) {
                from components.java
                versionMapping {
                    usage('java-api') {
                        fromResolutionOf('runtimeClasspath')
                    }
               usage('java-runtime') {
                   fromResolutionResult()
               }
            }
         }
     }
   }
  tasks.named('compileJava') {
        inputs.files(tasks.named('processResources'))
  }
 dependencies {
     implementation 'io.nats:nats-spring:0.5.6'
     testImplementation 'org.junit.vintage:junit-vintage-engine:5.9.0'
     testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test:2.6.3'
     testImplementation 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:5.9.0'
     testImplementation 'org.junit.platform:junit-platform-engine:1.9.0'
        testImplementation 'org.junit.platform:junit-platform-launcher:1.8.2'
    testImplementation 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.9.0'
    implementation('np.com.madanpokharel.embed:nats-embedded:2.1.0')
   }

  tasks.named('test') {
   useJUnitPlatform()
 }
```

I am using `./gradlew build` task which generates a jar and with this jar I am not able to get the `NatsProperties` class methods.

But if I use `fatJar` task from this `shadow` plugin I am able to get the methods but thing is its creating all of the libraries and size is too big.

Comment: if I export it as `fatJar` its working.

Comment: That sounds like the dependencies of the library are not retrieved. Are you distributing the library as a simple jar file, or as a maven artifact with pom.xml in a repository?

Comment: @slindenau please see my question, I added library`build.gradle`

Comment: And how do you add this library to your project that is using it?

Comment: @slindenau `implementation 'com.dexter:streaming-client:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'` like this

Comment: @slindenau weird part is I am able to connect to streaming server using this library and able to publish as well, but just this class `StreamingServerProperties` is not able to grab super class methods and its members.

Comment: So only an issue in the IDE? Maybe it's not synced with the gradle dependencies?

Comment: @slindenau I am not sure if its IDE issue, or its actually not able to export those classes. how do we try without IDE involvement ?

Comment: I'm no gradle expert sadly, but if the code is executing without problems it looks like the library is loaded just fine. Did you try something like this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32652738/how-can-i-force-update-all-the-snapshot-gradle-dependencies-in-intellij

Comment: I tried that too, it didnt work either.

Comment: I am able to solve it by making dependencies in `streaming-server-client` as `api ` instead of `implementation`

Comment: Great, if you want you can write up your solution and [answer your own question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer). Try to explain why it works with these settings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to solve it by adding dependency as an `api`

instead of

```
   implementation 'io.nats:nats-sprin:0.5.6' // this adds to runtimeclass path
```

I tried this

```
   api 'io.nats:nats-sprin:0.5.6' //this adds to both compile and runtime
```

As I am using `java-library` gradle plugin.

Answer (score 0):

Can you add this dependency so intellij will generate the configuration metadata for you in `target`

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
    <optional>true</optional>
</dependency>
```

Comment: I have tried this, still I am not able to access the methods of that calls at client side.